# Name for semiring with multiplicative inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Is there a name for a commutative semiring with multiplicative inverse? Or equivalently a field without additive inverse?

I came across this structure recently and I'm looking for relevant literature about it. The name would definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semiring whose elements have multiplicative inverses is called a 
[semifield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semifield).

Comment: But semifield has an additive inverse, hasn't it?

Comment: @outmind Not in the semiring-theoretic context.